# Backing up a disk image with Time Machine

Tags: macos, mac, time-machine

I'm storing backup of my Gmail account in a disk image, to cut on number of files on the main HFS+ volume. This makes Time Machine ignore the existence of this volume, just because it's in a disk image.

Is it possible to get Time Machine to treat the disk image as a regular disk, and get Time Machine to back it up as if it were a "physical" volume?

This is on Mountain Lion 10.8.2, on late 2009 white unibody Macbook.

Comment: You can’t back it up as a physical volume, it will back up as a dmg file. Not sure, really.

Comment: I was asking precisely because I'm interested if I can force Time Machine to treat this volume as a physical one. I'm only separating it to make HFS+ happier and snappier.

Comment: I have the same question, but with different goals - I'm trying to convince Time Machine to create a local snapshot on APFS so that I can get some test data.

Answer (score 1):

To back up a disk image, you back up the `.dmg`file itself, instead of the virtual disk the system shows you.

However, unless the disk image is a sparse bundle image. Time machine will have to backup the entire disk every time the disk changes.

Comment: Can this be done while the disk image is mounted? If so, how does it avoid problems with the image being modified during the back up process?